# Теоретический вопрос по DataGridView, DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Вопрос по классам winForms C#.

У класса DataGridViewRow есть свойство только для чтения DataGridView, у него есть только геттер (поле только для чтения).

```
//создаем объект DataGridViewRow
DataGridViewRow currentRow = new DataGridViewRow();
// смотрим здесь у currentRow.DataGridView равно null
dataGridSettings.Rows.Add(currentRow);
// смотрим здесь у currentRow.DataGridView равно dataGridSettings
```

Вопрос: откуда currentRow взял dataGridSettings, если поле  DataGridView у него закрытое для записи? Разве может быть поле доступно из одного класса или недоступно из другого? Или, допустим, у него есть скрытый сеттер, но почему опять же этот сеттер виден в другом классе, а в клиентском не виден?

Я хочу написать свой DataGridView, и эта механика в прототипе мне неясна.

Comment: А почему WinForms? 2014 год на дворе, переходите на WPF, и ваши волосы будут мягкими и шелковистыми.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть, например, модификатор internal, который позволяет "видеть" свойства и методы в одной сборке (библиотеке).